# send email from multi-lined grep output

Tags: grep, tail

doesn't grab $ERROR and no email or killing the tail. what am i doing wrong?

```
tail -F --max-unchanged-stats=5 somelogfile.log | grep -B4 "FATAL" | while read ERROR
do
    echo $ERROR | mail -s 'FATAL ERROR' admin@someserver.com && pkill -P $$ tail
done
```

Comment: This question is likely  duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656886/tail-and-grep-log-and-mail-linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "--line-buffered" to the grep command. But as stated in the answer by @Nick, you will get an email for each line. May want to just remove the "-B4" argument from the grep command.

```
tail -F --max-unchanged-stats=5 somelogfile.log | grep -B4 --line-buffered "FATAL" | while 
read ERROR
do
    echo "$ERROR" | mail -s 'FATAL ERROR' admin@someserver.com
done
```

Try this. I tested on my CentOS 6.9 VM and I believe it does what you are looking to accomplish. When the script is first started, you may get a few emails if there are "FATAL" messages near the bottom of the log file.

```
#!/bin/bash

tail -f --max-unchanged-stats=5 somelogfile.log | grep --line-buffered "FATAL" | while read ERROR
do
    grep -B4 "$ERROR" somelogfile.log \
    | mail -s 'FATAL ERROR' admin@someserver.com
done
```

Comment: well i need the last 4 lines to be emailed from grep output would there be another approach to this?

Comment: @Khorem, try the script I added to my answer. Note that the '`-B4` argument is removed from the first `grep`.

Comment: I was thinking it was something you would want to run in a continuous loop. Glad I can help.

Answer (score 0):

tail and grep probably buffer stdout, so the while loop does not see it. If you have `stdbuf` (it should be available on Linux, but I'm not sure about other systems), try

```
stdbuf -o0 tail -F --max-unchanged-stats=5 somelogfile.log | stdbuf -o0 grep -B4 "FATAL" | while read ERROR ;do ... ;done
```

But there is another problem: The `while read ERROR` will read one line and assign it to ERROR each time around the loop. Your grep prints four lines before the FATAL line, so you'd be sending five emails, not one.